# css3pie box shadow not working in ie8

Tags: jquery, css, css3pie

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div {
position:relative;
border: 1px solid #696;
padding: 60px 0;
text-align: center; width: 200px;
-webkit-box-shadow: #666 0px 0px 8px;
-moz-box-shadow: #666 0px 0px 8px;
box-shadow: #666 0px 0px 8px;
background: #EEFF99;
behavior: url(http://css3pie.com/pie/PIE.php);}</style>
</head>
<body>

<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I have searched alot on the net, and tried all the possible option i got, but still it does not seems to be working,

please anybody suggest what I am missing?

**As jsfiddle does not seems to be working in IE8, you can check here **http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_box-shadow** and replace html with given html above**

Thanks

Comment: it's working. what is your browser

Comment: Its mentioned in title, IE8

Comment: It says in the [documentation](http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/#content-type) that you need to set _content-type_ if your using `PIE.php` with apache.

Comment: I tried with PIE.htc, but still its not working

Comment: if you check this link http://css3pie.com/, its seems working, but my code is not working :(

Comment: even if you remove behave and test in other browsers or even IE 8+ , it seems working

Comment: The 'behavior' property is limited to the same domain, so requesting it from css3pie.com will not work. Do you still have issues when you host it on your local domain?

Answer (score 0):

Please download the zip file (http://css3pie.com/download-latest-1.x) and you will get solution.

[image]

You need to add above files into your projects

Try it.